# How to build a JAR file using Netbeans 8.0.2?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to create and extension file using NetBeans for my smart fox server 2x. I am following a video tutorial and when the instructor in the video says to build your project (via the little hammer icon) to create the JAR file, well, my hammer icon is disabled.

My question is: How do I enable it? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you can enable it, but there are other ways to build it.

1. Right-click the project's node in the Projects window and choose Build.
2. Choose Run > Build  Project
3. Choose Run > Clean and Build project

Comment: It is greyed out, every part of my project I go is greyed out

Comment: Did you run the file at least one time? If you didn't than you can't build it.

Comment: It is greyed out. I can't get to it

Comment: Also the "Run File" if you right click on the code? Even Shift+F6 not working?

Comment: Nope, it is greyed out, disabled. I can't get to it

Comment: Well, it's strange because it should always be enabled. Try to terminate Netbeans and start it again (maybe you will need to do this multiple times), or change the project folder name in Windows explorer.

Comment: That worked! I just had to close Netbeans. Thank you. I can tell from here on out using this program is going to be a pain. That's why I am more of a Visual Studios guy.